# I'm having trouble with an excercise that involves calculating the length of a chord by the way its divided by the circles diameter

Tags: circles, triangles

I'm failing to understand how to even start this exercise. The exercise goes as follows: theres a chord in a circle. It is divided by 2 perpendicular diameters of the circle. It is divided into 1:3:2 the radius of the circle is r.
Calculate the length of the chord.

I have sketched it multiple times trying to draw different triangles inside it (which I'm pretty sure is the way to solve it), but I just don't get anywhere.
The main Problem I think is sketching the Problem differently, to make is make more sense, but I just can't see that.

Can somebody just give me a little hint on how to go forward?

Heres a sketch of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call $\;O,\,M,\,N\;$ to the points "center of the circle, intersection of the vertical diameter with the chord, and intersection of the horizontal diameter with the chord", resp .

By the [Chords Theorem](http://www.mathopenref.com/chordsintersecting.html) , we get:

$$\begin{align*}&\text{By the vertical diameter}:\;x\cdot 5x=(r+OM)(\overbrace{2r-(r+OM)}^{=r-OM})\implies 5x^2=r^2-OM^2\\{}\\
&\text{By the horizontal diameter:}\;(x+3x)\cdot2x=r^2-ON^2\implies8x^2=r^2-ON^2\end{align*}$$

and from here (pass your mouse on the following if you want the solution):

> $$OM^2=r^2-5x^2\;,\;\;ON^2=r^2-8x^2$$

and by Pythagoras teorem applied in the straight triangle $\;\Delta OMN\;$ (observe that $\;MN=3x$):

> $$2r^2-13x^2=9x^2\implies 22x^2=2r^2\implies x=\frac r{\sqrt{11}}>$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote the points on the chord as $A,B,C,D$ from top left to lower right. Let $O$ be the centre of the circle.
Let $P$ be the intersection of $OB$ and the parallel to $OC$ through $A$.
Let $Q$ be the intersection of $OC$ and the parallel to $OB$ through $D$.
Then the three triangles $ABP$, $CBO$, $CDQ$ are similar right triangles.
Let $u=AP$, $v=BP$. Then Pythagoras applied to the right triangles $ABP$, $AOP$, and $ODQ$ gives us
$$\begin{align}\tag1u^2+v^2&=x^2\\
\tag2u^2+(v+3v)^2&=r^2\\
\tag3(3u+2u)^2+(2v)^2&=r^2
\end{align}$$
We want to find the lenth  $\ell=6x$ from this.
To do so, combine $(2)$ and $(3)$ suitably to obtain the a multiple of $u^2+v^2$ on the left.

> As it turns out, $7(2)+5(3)$ gives us $(7+5)r^2=(7+5\cdot 25)u^2+(7\cdot 16+5\cdot 4)v^2=132\cdot(u^2+x^2)=132 x^2$ and so $r^2=11x^2$.

Finally,

> $$\ell=6x=\frac{6r}{\sqrt {11}}.$$

Comment: Nevermind this comment

Comment: Nevermind this comment aswell, I took me while to understand your reasoning, sorry

Comment: I still don't entirely get what 7(2)+5(3) means and how you were able to generate the formula of this, could be a bit more specific on how you did that?